# React Formik with a custom component : lifting state up while validating

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to use Formik on my form that successfully does some *state lift up* from a custom Input child component to its parent (following that [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from React's official website)

The following sandbox shows a basic example of what I have so far :
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-with--or-without-custom-component-d8sof
(yes, there is some *styled-components* going on with InputStyled but it's supposed to be "transparent")

```
          <Input //switch to input to try other scenario
            type="number"
            name="surface"
            placeholder="please type surface"
            onValueChange={handleSurfaceChange}
            unit="sq feet"
            value={values.surface}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
```

The excerpt above shows a custom component called Input (please note the capitalized "I")

With this custom component Input : lifting state up works but surface is not tracked by Formik and validation always fails.

With input (lower case - not calling my custom component) : validation by Formik works but I'm not using my custom component therefore I'm not engaging in the lifting of the child state up.
=> My goal would be to make both work.

So I tried using `<Field component={Input} />` instead of my `<Input />`
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field

But I cannot get my head around how to make the code work.

I started working on another codesanbox example following different trails here and there but things are getting messy.

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-with--or-without-custom-component-ybbm7

In the parent:

```
<Field
            component={Input} //my custom React Component
            type="number"
            name="surface"
            placeholder="please type surface"
            onValueChange={handleSurfaceChange}
            value={values.surface}
            //at a loss below
            //onChange={handleChange}
            // handleChange={e => {
            //   console.log("Entering handleChange in Field...");
            //   // call the built-in handleChange
            //   handleChange(e);
            //   // and do something about e
            //   let someValue = e.currentTarget.value;
            //   console.log("someValue = " + someValue);
            // }}
          />
```

In the child (it's a styled-component, nothing fancy,just a regular input "decorated" with CSS) :

```
<InputStyled
        {...field}
        {...props}
        id={props.name}
        name={props.name}
        type={props.type}
        //value={props.value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        // onChange={newValue => {
        //   setFieldValue(field.name, newValue);
        //   console.log("newValue = " + newValue);
        // }}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      />
      {touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && (
        <div className="error">{errors[field.name]}</div>
      )}
```

I cannot find the right way to deal with the onChange, handleChange events from Formik and from myself. the lifting of the state up and the Formik validations are broken.

Can someone point me in the right direction for the correct syntax please ?